# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (Tried prev solutions)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, sigabrt

I can't seem to figure out this Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error. My app stops at the launch screen with only the title displayed. I've checked to see if there are any rogue outlets as mentioned in other solutions but it seems fine. Here is the log:

```
 2016-06-14 12:50:22.760 Flight4[92201:6597548] Unknown class MainViewController in Interface Builder file.
2016-06-14 12:50:22.777 Flight4[92201:6597548] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f91c0694330> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccb2c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e81dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccb28a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010d0d0b53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbfad50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d8294eb -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d6816d8 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d681cc8 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d681f39 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d6823ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d59d289 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d59d64f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d5a9de1 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d54d417 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d55019e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d54f095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112ef65e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbe641c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbdc165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbdbf25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbdb366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010d54eb02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010d5518c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  Flight4                             0x000000010ca2bc87 main + 135
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f51d145 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The first line says "Unknown class MainViewController in Interface Builder file." but the class is linked to a view controller on the main storyboard and does not contain any errors. Could the error be related to this file? If so, I'm not sure how else to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: are all outlets are properly connected ? ,

Comment: Yes, I ctrl+right clicked on all my views and the outlets seem fine (no yellow warnings.)

Comment: Go to the connections inspector in the Main.storyboard, and delete the tableView one, and connect it again. Might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for this problem. I went to the Identity Inspector for MainViewController and under Custom Class, I set the Module which was previously undefined (see photo).[image]

However, now I have a new error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Must translate autoresizing mask into constraints to have _setHostsLayoutEngine:YES.'
```

in regards to my cell. I have attached a picture of the view hierarchy. [image]